# How to continue a for loop with a 504 Gateway Timeout error response from an API?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, lob, http-status-code-504

I am using a package called lob to standardize a dataset of addresses I have. I have been receiving a 504 gateway error after running through a few thousand addresses. The response error from Lob is the following:

```
.......Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "verify_modified_v2.py", line 82, in <module>
    zip_code=row['zip_code'],
  File "C:\Users\******\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\lob\resource.py", line 123, in create
    response = requestor.request('post', cls.endpoint, params)
  File "C:\Users\******\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\lob\api_requestor.py", line 84, in request
    requests.post(lob.api_base + url, auth=(self.api_key, ''), data=data, files=files, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\******\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\lob\api_requestor.py", line 27, in parse_response
    resp.content, resp.status_code, resp)
lob.error.APIConnectionError: {
    "error": {
        "message": "GATEWAY_TIMEOUT",
        "status_code": 504
    }
}
```

I have tried to except this error so that my code can repeatedly contact lob until it can get through without the gateway error:

```
for idx, row in enumerate(input_csv):
        try:
            verifiedAddress = lob.USVerification.create(
                primary_line=row['primary_line'],
                secondary_line=row['secondary_line'],
                city=row['city'],
                state=row['state'],
                zip_code=row['zip_code'],
            )

            if verifiedAddress.deliverability in success_deliverabilities:
                success_csv.writerow({
                    'primary_line': verifiedAddress.primary_line,
                    'secondary_line': verifiedAddress.secondary_line,
                    'urbanization':  verifiedAddress.urbanization,
                    'last_line':  verifiedAddress.last_line,
                    'deliverability': verifiedAddress.deliverability,
                    'identifier': row['identifier'],
                    'status': row['2']
                })
            else:
                failure_csv.writerow({
                    'primary_line': row['primary_line'],
                    'secondary_line': row['secondary_line'],
                    'city':  row['city'],
                    'state':  row['state'],
                    'zip_code':  row['zip_code'],
                    'deliverability': verifiedAddress.deliverability,
                    'identifier': row['identifier'],
                    'status': row['2']
                })

            # Print success
            sys.stdout.write('.')
            sys.stdout.flush()

             # New lines for larger csv's
            if idx % 10 is 9:
                sys.stdout.write('\n')
                sys.stdout.flush()

        except lob.error.APIConnectionError:
            print "caught error"
```

It does not seem that the gateway error is able to be "excepted"; does anyone have any thoughts on a way around this?

My end goal is this:

1. Bypass the error.
2. Log the error.
3. Continue with the next row of the csv file.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you need an `except` after `try`?

Comment: The except is at the bottom of the code block

Comment: Hmm, my eyes must be playing tricks on me, could have sworn that said `finally`. Anyway, what are you seeing?

Comment: @ballpointben I'm at a bit of a loss. I'm not sure how to format my code so that when I receive this response from lob it will continue running:

`lob.error.APIConnectionError: {
    "error": {
        "message": "GATEWAY_TIMEOUT",
        "status_code": 504
    }
}`

Comment: Change that line to `except Exception:`; now what happens?

Comment: Running it now. It looks like that is working actually, thanks @ballpointben Will report back once it claims entire csv has been ran through the script.

Comment: In general you should be more specific than `except Exception`; I only proposed that as a debugging step. I’m still not sure what the underlying issue is.

Comment: Yes it helped with debugging, just got through an enormous csv file. I'm working on how to display the specific error that the code excepts. Any thoughts?

Comment: `except Exception as e:` ... `print(e)`